# How to show posts from a selected category?

Tags: wordpress, post, categories, selected

I am trying to show all post from a selected category. For example i have two category like Health & Recipe. I am trying to show all post of health category in health page/part and all recipe's post in recipe part/page. I am using the following code to do it. But i cannot understand why it's showing all health & recipe post together. Please help me to solve this and if possible please suggest me the whole code.
Thanks

```
<div class="media-body">
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php // Display blog posts on any page @ http://m0n.co/l
    $temp = $wp_query; 
    $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
    $wp_query->query('showposts=4' .        '&paged='.$paged);
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    ?>
        <div class="featuredimage">
            <?php
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail(); 
            }
            ?>
        </div><!-- end of featured image -->
        <h4 class="media-heading articlehead ">"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        <h5 class="date"><small> Posted by : abc</small></h5>
        <div class="post_content">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div><!-- end of post content -->

        <div class="postinfo">
            <div class="col-sm-6 postinfo">
                <h5 class="date"><small> Posted on : <?php the_time('M d, Y') ?> </small>  </h5>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 text-right postinfo">
                <h5><small><span class="comment"><?php comments_popup_link('No Comment',    '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?><i class="fa fa-comment-o "></i>  (3)</span><span class="comment"> <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>  (39)</span></small></h5>
            </div>

        </div><!-- end of post info -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

 </div> <!-- end of media body -->
```

Comment: Have a look at the [category parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters), you have a line here `$wp_query->query('showposts=4' .        '&paged='.$paged);`, use this line and pass category parameter to get desired category posts only.

Comment: Would you write a few more because i tried as you said but it's not working. i tried as belows  $wp_query->query('showposts=4' . '&paged='.$paged . 'cat=4');

Comment: Concatenate each parameter using an ampersand (`&`): `$wp_query->query('showposts=4' . '&paged='.$paged .'&cat=4');`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Category Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) of a WordPress query.

You have a line here `$wp_query->query('showposts=4' . '&paged='.$paged);`.

You just need to pass the category credentials to the query - it's simple. It can be like this, passing simply the category ID:

```
$wp_query->query('showposts=4' . '&paged='.$paged .'&cat=4');
```

As you are using the non-array format of the query, you have to concatenate each parameter using an ampersand (`&`). That's it - simple.